# How to call plugin functions in a custom template

Tags: plugins, front-end

I want to try calling the pre-defined functions from the [front end private messages plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/) in my custom template. But It shows that the function does not exist. But that function is working fine in the plugin.

What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There can be various reason for the undefined function error:

- The plugin might load its function definitions later than `template_include` or in the admin backend only.
- You might have made a syntax error, for example if the plugin is using a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), but you are calling the function without that namespace. Or the function is really a class method, and you treat it as a function …

Another question is: Why would you call that function directly? Templates should have as little dependencies as possible. Imagine someone finds a security problem in the plugin, and you have to turn it off. Do you really want to edit all your template files then? Probably not. :)

It is much better to keep that dependency out of the template and call a custom action instead. For example, in your template you can replace the direct call with an action call:

```
do_action( 'frontend.message' );
```

In your theme's `functions.php`, you register a callback for that action:

```
add_action( 'frontend.message', 'my_frontend_message' );

function my_frontend_message()
{
    if ( ! function_exists( 'plugin_frontend_message' ) ) {

        // Show debug info for those who can do something about it.
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_option' ) ) {
            print '<p class="error">Function plugin_frontend_message() not found.</p>';
        }
        return;
    }

    print plugin_frontend_message();
}
```

If you turn off the plugin now, nothing bad will happen, your visitors will just see nothing instead of a message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check documentation of plugin (to now more about function)
2. Than check the function if is static You can use

   `ClassName::FunctionName`
3. If not check if there is global object added by plugin

   `global $plugin_name_object;
   $plugin_name_object->my_function();`
4. if not simply create `new object` of plugin and call this function.

   `obj = new Plugin();
    $obj->my_function();`